# Tensorflow Convolution Neural Network Negative Dimension size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am building this CNN model,
'''

```
x_test = np.array(x_test).reshape(-1,IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,1)
x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(-1,IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,1)


model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))  
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(2,2),padding='same')) 
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

'''

But this is giving me an error:-
InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_115/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_115/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,32], [2,2,32,64].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_115/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_115/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,32], [2,2,32,64].

What does this error mean? What I am doing wrong? Please help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

It might mean, due to the layers like maxpooling, and conv2d with 'valid' padding value, the input to some layers got so small that it has the shape of the tensor is [?,1,1,32], thus it cannot perform a 2D maxpooling or 2D convolution with size 2. In this case you need to re-design the layers based on your input size (meaning that change the number of the layers, or input size, stride, padding option, ...).